# Multivariate row subsetting of data.table based on vectors

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for an elegant way of dynamically subsetting a `data.table` based on variable-length vectors, indicating the columns to be searched respectively the values to be matched.

In order to illustrate the problem, I have a `data.table` as follows:

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 3), b = c(2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 5), c = c(4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 1))
dt
```

```
   a b c
1: 1 2 4
2: 3 3 2
3: 2 5 5
4: 5 1 2
5: 4 6 5
6: 1 2 2
7: 3 5 1
```

Now I have a variable-length vector of column names `cols` which is an arbitrary subset of the column names in `dt`, e.g:

```
cols <- c("b", "c")
```

Given that vector, I have a vector with the corresponding length `vals` with values to which the columns indicated in `cols` have to be matched, e.g.:

```
vals <- c(6, 5)
```

I managed to do this with a straightforward for loop, which is replacing `dt` by every iteration:

```
for (i in 1:length(cols)) {
  dt <- dt[eval(parse(text = cols[i])) == vals[i], ]
}
dt
```

and received the desired result:

```
   a b c
1: 4 6 5
```

What I am just wondering is if there is a less chunky one-line command which would also save plenty of runtime, particularly if we apply this code to very large `data.tables` and also bigger amounts of subsetting parameters assigned by `cols` and `vals`.

Comment: What would be the example of input/output for 'bigger amounts of subsetting parameters'?

Comment: not easy to post a reproducible example here. but let's say, if dt is a large data.table with more than 500k rows and 100 columns and cols conists of 50 elements. in that case, the for loop I posted would pass thru 50 iterations, applying the subset command on the large dataset again and again. In that case, a one-line command which is subsetting dt only once at a time, would save a lot of runtime. That's why I was wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setkeyv(dt, cols)
dt[as.list(vals)]
#    a b c
# 1: 4 6 5
```

Comment: And also `dt[setNames(as.list(vals), cols), on=.NATURAL]`